# A way of writing large numeral literals in C#

Tags: c#, numbers, decimal, literals

I have a method like this:

```
Prefix GetPrefix(decimal value)
{
    if(value > 11000000000000000000)
        return Prefix.CosmicBig;
    if(value > 1000000000000000)
        return Prefix.ReallyBig;
    if(value > 3000000000000)
        return Prefix.Big;
    if(value > 50000000)
        return Prefix.Okay;
    if(value > 750000)
        return Prefix.MostlyNormal;
    if(value > 750000)
        return Prefix.SoSo;
    if(value > 750)
        return Prefix.Small;
    return Prefix.MiserablySmall;
}
```

The exact values are not important. What matters is that they are sometimes changed (the prefixes are used for drawing and some text areas change sizes in development). I'm looking for a way of writing these literals in a way that's easily readably by a human changing it, without having to count all the zeroes. A separator would be nice. I thought about writing `11 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000`, but that's only barely more manageable. Using `Math.Pow()` does it a little better, but I'm not comfortable with using such calculations to define constants.

Comment: The speed of light in meters per second is okay, but pi is miserably small... :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can introduce extension methods for `int`:

```cs
750.Thousand();
5.Million();
100.Billion();
```

The implementation of these methods is simple:

```
public static int Thousand(this int value)
{
    return value * 1000;
}

public static int Million(this int value)
{
    return value.Thousand() * 1000;
}

// etc.
```

Make sure to return the appropriate data type for methods for bigger numbers:

```
public static long Billion(this int value)
{
    return value.Million() * 1000;
}
```

Unfortunatelly, you will have to write those methods for every integral or floating point type you want to support.

Having a full set of such extension methods would allow you to express your large numbers in relativly natural ways, even when it's not just all zeros at the end:

```
100.Billion() + 30.Thousand() + 300 // == 100,000,030,300
```

If you want to get fancy, you could even think about nesting them:

```
100.Billion(30.Thousand(300))
```

But I think that would lose some expressiveness, because people would wonder what the parameter means.

Still, implementation would look like this:

```
public static long Billion(this int value, long add)
{
    return value.Million() * 1000 + add;
}
```

---

Using these extension methods has one little downside: Your numbers are no longer compile-time constants. They are calculated at runtime. In the vast majority of cases, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Sure. That's extension methods.

Comment: This is so cool. I was wondering recently under what circumstances would I want to call an instance method of a number.

Comment: @Allrameest my point is that you would need `99..thousand()` or `(99).thousand()` in Javascript, since the period gets parsed as a decimal point. PS: `document.write` is bad.

Answer (score 22):

Instead of `11000000000000000000` you can use `11e18`. Use `m` to indicate that it is a decimal, so `11e18m`.

Answer (score 1):

A language feature introduced on C# 7.0 is the introduction of `_` as a digit separator when inside number literals, so instead of `50000000` you can write `50_000_000`.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/new-features-in-c-7-0/#literal-improvements

For very large numbers, or if working with numbers in scientific notation, the solution given by [Sjoerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182971/sjoerd) might be a better option.